# How do i stop counter setting state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a component where I have a asteroid object with multiple values. and  have days: 1 in my state. where i render my asteroid i do * times what every value to get the value for the asteroid per day. what i want to do is to stop counting when the total mass of the asteroid == to the totalSumMined.the total sum mined is the total of all the chemicals mined.  i tried a few things but nothing works. this is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
//import * as uuid from "uuid";

class Stock extends Component {
  state = {
    asteroid: { ...this.props },
    days: 1,
  };
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ days: prevState.days + 1 }));
  };

  render() {
    const remainingMpct = parseInt(this.state.asteroid.remainingMpct);
    console.log(typeof remainingMpct);
    const nickel = this.state.asteroid.chemPerDay[0];
    const iron = this.state.asteroid.chemPerDay[1];
    const cobalt = this.state.asteroid.chemPerDay[2];
    const water = this.state.asteroid.chemPerDay[2];
    const nirtogen = this.state.asteroid.chemPerDay[4];
    const ammonia = this.state.asteroid.chemPerDay[5];
    // console.log(nickel, iron, cobalt, water, nirtogen, "NICKEL");

    return (
      <div className="stock">
        <p>
          - Day {this.state.days}
          <button type="button" className="inButton" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            +
          </button>{" "}
        </p>
        <hr />
        <p> - mass nickel: {nickel * this.state.days} </p>
        <p> - mass iron: {iron * this.state.days} </p>
        <p> - mass cobalt: {cobalt * this.state.days} </p>
        <p> - mass water: {water * this.state.days} </p>
        <p> - mass nitogen: {nirtogen * this.state.days} </p>
        <p> - mass ammonia: {ammonia * this.state.days} </p>
        <hr />
        <p>
          - Total mass mined:{" "}
          {this.state.asteroid.totalSumMined * this.state.days ===
          this.state.asteroid.asteroid.mass
            ? null
            : this.state.asteroid.totalSumMined * this.state.days}
        </p>

        <p>- remaing mass: {remainingMpct / this.state.days}%</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Stock;
```

Comment: I guess you need to disable your click or stop increment of days when both the mass and chemical thing are equal, please correct me.

Comment: Did you try wrapping "setState" with an if statement to control your condition in the handleClick method?

Comment: yes.  and also yes to tried to wrapping setstate in if statement

Comment: Can you show how you used the `if` block?

Comment: handleClick = () => {
    const mass = this.state.asteroid.asteroid.mass;
    const total = this.state.asteroid.totalSumMined;
    if (total < mass) {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({ days: prevState.days + 1 }));
    } else {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({ days: prevState.days }));
    }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand the calculation in your question but maybe you could do something like this?

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Stock extends Component {
  constructor(props: { asteroid: Asteroid }) {
    super(props);
    // What is the point of putting asteroid in state when you never change the asteroid's state?
    this.state = {
      days: 1
    };
  }

  get isFullyMined() {
    // object destructuring might clean up your code a bit.
    const { totalSumMined, mass } = this.props.asteroid;
    return totalSumMined >= mass;
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    // condition to stop changing state
    if (!this.isFullyMined) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ days: prevState.days + 1 }));
    }
  };

  render() {
    // object destructuring might clean up your code a bit.
    const {
      remainingMpct,
      totalSumMined,
      mass,
      chemPerDay: [nickel, iron, cobalt, water, nitrogen, ammonia] // why not use an object instead of an array, it would be more robust
    } = this.props.asteroid;

    // using the getter to disable the button is a nice usability change
    return (
      <div className="stock">
        <p>
          - Day {this.state.days}
          <button
            type="button"
            className="inButton"
            onClick={this.handleClick}
            disabled={this.isFullyMined}
          >
            +
          </button>{" "}
        </p>
        <hr />
        <p> - mass nickel: {nickel * this.state.days} </p>
        <p> - mass iron: {iron * this.state.days} </p>
        <p> - mass cobalt: {cobalt * this.state.days} </p>
        <p> - mass water: {water * this.state.days} </p>
        <p> - mass nitrogen: {nitrogen * this.state.days} </p>
        <p> - mass ammonia: {ammonia * this.state.days} </p>
        <hr />
        <p>
          - Total mass mined:{" "}
          {totalSumMined * this.state.days >= mass
            ? null
            : totalSumMined * this.state.days}
        </p>

        <p>- remainig mass: {remainingMpct / this.state.days}%</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Stock;
```

Comment: @lydia michael did any of the purposed solutions work for you?

Comment: @lydia michael, Glad to hear it! Could you do me a favour and mark the answer as accepted! It would make me and everyone here on stackoverflow very happy :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to implement the `getDerivedStateFromProps` method. Your click handler depends on the state properties which are set by the props. So, you need to update your state whenever your props change their value.

In your component,

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  return {
    asteroid: { ...props },
    days: state.days,
  };
}
```